# Oracle Weblogic Java JDK in Windows

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic

So I have updated Java JDK (current version was out of date) on my Windows Server and the JAVA_HOME for this now sits alongside the original install.  I cannot seem to find where in Weblogic it needs repointing to the new JDK install.

I have updated the Environment Variables to point to the new JAVA_HOME

Comment: If you start your weblogic server instances with scripts, you have to update the setDomainEnv.cmd script in all your domains.

Comment: Yes I read the limited documentation by the software supplier @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen as well as researching online, but nothing that i could use

Comment: thanks @EmmanuelCollin This is right, i adjusted the JAVA_HOME here and it worked